# After logging in display another template in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor, I am trying to display another Template if user is already Logged in

```
    {{#if currentUser }}
      <p>You are logged in</p>
      {{> afterLogin}}
  {{else}}
      <div class="container">
      <div class="clearfix" style="height:50px" ><br></div>
      {{> loginForm }}
      {{> registerForm }}
      </div>
  {{/if}}
```

Using this code in Login Template. But, this code displays previous templates. I don't know where and how to use yield here.

Please help me to understand this problem

Thank you

Comment: Your code looks ok at first glance, but what do you mean by `Using this code in Login Template`?  If you are just using Blaze you don't use `yield`. Are you using `iron:router` and `LayoutTemplates`?

Comment: @JeremyK I created template with name Login. If user is logged in it should display template afterLogin. Yes, am using iron:router but not LayoutTemplates. I feel I can do it with iron:routing, can you help me how to route once user logged in.

Comment: you'll need to provide more code.  what you have above looks ok